# Inverse of Times->Sequence

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose there is a list

`list={abc}`

then the replacement `Times->Sequence` gives

`list/.Times->Sequence
{a,b,c}`

How to do the inverse operation, how from `{a,b,c}` get `{a b c}`?

Comment: You could do this: `Times @@@ {{a, b, c}}`.

Comment: That works! Thank you! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I did, but don't rush to accept it just yet, let's see what other solutions will be posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest I have is

```
list={a, b, c}
list /. g_[x__] :> g[Times[x]]
```

or

```
f[g_[x__]] := g[Times[x]]
f[list]
```

The problem is that Sequence "disappears" in your original code, i.e. when you run

```
list/.Times->Sequence
{a,b,c}
```

you have reduced

```
List[Times[a,b,c]]
```

into

```
List[a,b,c]
```

Conceptually you want to make the Sequence "reappear" i.e. as

```
List[Sequence[a,b,c]]
```

which happens when you use the "__" pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That is exactly my problem. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

with this as your starting list

```
list = {{a, b, c}}
```

you could also do this

```
list[[1, 0]] = Times; list
```